# C3321: an initializer list is unexpected in this context

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

In my code I have some statements like this:

```
auto buffer = boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>>(new std::vector<uint8_t>() { 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x03, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00 });
```

With Visual Studio 2013 these lines compiled without any problems. But with Visual Studio 2015 I get the following error:

> C3321: an initializer list is unexpected in this context

What is wrong with the above statement?

Comment: Is c++11 activated in the compiler settings?

Comment: `new std::vector<uint8_t>(){ 1, 2 }` is not valid (extra `()`), `new std::vector<uint8_t>{ 1, 2 }` is

Comment: Thanks Piotr, that helped! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New-initializer syntax accepts either `()` with an optional expression list  inside, *or*, a braced initializer list, not both, so just remove the redundant `()` before opening the braced initializer list that follows:

```
auto buffer = boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>>(
                    new std::vector<uint8_t> { 0x0A, 0x00, /**/ }
//                                          ~^~                ~^~
              );
```

Comment: Now the question is... what Visual Studio 2013 was doing?! creating an empty `boost::shared_ptr` and then *calling the `{}` operator*?! (yes, the `{}` operator is a joke).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster VS 2013 [calls an initalizer-list constructor](http://rextester.com/VIFH20248), ignoring any arguments inside `()`

Comment: It shocks me that MSVC ignores the `()` instead of marking it as a syntax error :O